# Silex - Controller class not found in route.php

Tags: php, silex, autoloader

I am building a web app with php silex as the backend.
I have the following directory structure:

```
bento
  \app
     \app.php
     \bootstrap.php
  \src
     \supervisor
         \SupervisorController.php
      \Application.php
      \routes.php
  \composer.json
  \vendor
```

The file contents are as follows;

pp.php

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

    $app = new Silex\Application();

    require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';

    return $app;

?>
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

?>
```

SupervisorController.php

```
<?php

namespace Bento\Supervisor\SupervisorController;

use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Silex\Application;

class SupervisorController implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Application $app) {

        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
        $app->get('/supervisor/processes', function() use ($app){

        });

        return $controllers;
    }

    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
        // TODO: Implement boot() method.
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
<?php

$app->mount('/supervisor', new \Bento\Supervisor\SupervisorController\SupervisorController());
```

composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "silex/silex": "~1.3"
  }
}
```

I get the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Bento\Supervisor\SupervisorController\SupervisorController' not found in /somedir/Documents/projects/mv2/bento/src/routes.php on line 3
```

I tried adding `"autoload": { "psr-4": { "": "./" } }` in `composer.json` but couldn't make it work

Answer (score 1):

Try to change controllers namespace to `Bento\Supervisor`. I don't think that namespace should contain class name.

```
namespace Bento\Supervisor;

use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Silex\Application;

class SupervisorController implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
```

and add autoload to composer

```
"autoload": { "psr-4": { "Bento\Supervisor": "./src/supervisor" } }
```